# match values with several conditions PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 Table in PowerBI.

Table 1 :

```
ID    Name       Email
1001  Henrik     henrik@x.com
1002  Lars       lars@x.com
1003  Fredrik    fredrik@x.com
1004             a@x.com
```

Table 2:

```
ID.    Name       Email
1003   Fred       fredrik@x.com
110
1001   Henrik     henrik@x.com
```

I want to compare their `Name` by matching the `ID`.

the Expected `Output` is

```
ID    Name       Name Result
1001  Henrik     No Difference
1002  Lars       Not Found Table 2
1003  Fredrik    Difference Value
1004             Empty in Table 1
```

I am completely lost how in PowerBI I can write a query that can give me the expected output. Any know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a **Calculated Column** in Table1:

```
=
VAR LookupResult =
    LOOKUPVALUE( Table2[Name], Table2[ID], Table1[ID] )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK( Table1[Name] ),
        "Empty in Table 1",
        SWITCH(
            LookupResult,
            BLANK(), "Not Found in Table 2",
            Table1[Name], "No Difference",
            "Difference Value"
        )
    )
```

Alternative to account for new requirement in which multiple names may exist for a given ID in Table2:

```
=
VAR ThisName = Table1[Name]
VAR ThisID = Table1[ID]
VAR LookupResult =
    0
        + (
            COUNTROWS( FILTER( Table2, Table2[Name] = ThisName && Table2[ID] = ThisID ) ) > 0
        )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK( Table1[Name] ),
        "Empty in Table 1",
        SWITCH(
            LookupResult,
            0, "Not Found in Table 2",
            1, "No Difference",
            "Difference Value"
        )
    )
```

Comment: thank you for the lightning-fast help. I am getting this error message when I am trying the query - "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Comment: The tables you posted don't contain duplicate entries. Are you saying that they in fact do? Does *Table2* contain multiple instances of a given ID, for example?

Comment: Jos in the real scenario where I am comparing values over a Million rows, that is the case. What do I need to do here when we have Multiple Instances with the Same ID

Comment: So for multiple cases if **ANY** of the names for that ID match then it should return "No Difference"?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Have added an alternative.